# How do I restart the "explorer.exe" shell with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, explorer

I want to restart the "explorer.exe" e.g. the TaskBar process with Delphi.

In a batch file I would do (works!):

```
taskkill.exe /IM explorer.exe /F
start explorer.exe
```

In Delphi I am trying to use ShellExecute for both commands. Killing works, however, I do not manage to get the explorer back.

How should I call ShellExecute to restart the explorer including taskbar (not just one single file browser window)?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having with `ShellExecute()`? Does it give you an error? Have you tried using `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`? Have you tried using `ShellExecute()`/`CreateProcess()` to run your batch file?

Comment: Was this batch copied from [How can I restart my taskbar?](https://superuser.com/a/583261/650342)

Answer (score -1):

It is a difference if you want to close the explorer windows or the taskbar. The explorer windows you can close by iterating through the windowlist using the getwindow function and send a wm_close message to all explorer windows. You can recognize the explorer windows by being 'CabinetWClass' or 'ExploreWClass' classtype.

The taskbar must be closed by finding the window with "Progman" title and killing that one, because it won't respond to wm_close. The taskbar should reopen automatically. Example function for closing the taskbar:

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wnd: hwnd;
  pid: dword;
  processhandle: thandle;
begin
  wnd := findwindow('Progman', NIL);
  IF wnd > 0 THEN
  BEGIN
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, pid);
    IF (pid > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
      processhandle := OpenProcess(1, false, pid);
      IF (processhandle > 0) THEN
      BEGIN
        TerminateProcess(processhandle, 0);
        CloseHandle(processhandle);
      END;
    END;
  END;
end;
```

Comment: Please link to documentation that spells out `"Progman"` as the reliable class name for the Taskbar window.

Comment: No, the Explorer/Taskbar only restarts automatically when [`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoRestartShell` is `1`](https://superuser.com/a/511915/650342).

Answer (score -4):

If explorer itself is not running, ShellExecute needs the full path, i.e. C:\Windows\explorer.exe in order to work.

Comment: Just like in your batch where you don't check the [`%errorlevel%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Windows) of what you execute, you most likely won't check what [`ShellExecute()` returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea#return-value). Assumptions are bad answers.

Comment: I did check return value, which was giving me "42" (no irony intended) whatever combination I chose. As 42 is above 32, no error is thrown.

Comment: Never call ShellExecute. Ever. Its error reporting is deficient. This is explained in its documentation. Required reading. That's why it has been replaced by ShellExecuteEx. But for this use don't call that either. Call CreateProcess. Why call ShellExecuteEx and ask it to call CreateProcess? Call CreateProcess directly.

Comment: I have now switched (and tried to, in the first place, but I couldn't get lpCommandLine working). However, thanks to your post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705532/access-violation-in-function-createprocess-in-delphi-2009) I have added `UniqueString` and now everything is running smoothly.

Comment: Then you used `CreateProcessW()` instead of `CreateProcessA()` - the former needs writable memory, the latter doesn't. [The documentation also tells you this!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa#parameters) That's why both Q and A should contain actual code you're using instead of prosa.